# Xcode always launches all device builds through GDB even though a normal launch is attempted

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an issue where Xcode **always** launches my device builds through GDB. Even though I choose "Build & Run" and not "Build & Debug" from the Build menu it launches through GDB. My simulator launches works as they're supposed to - through GDB only when I choose "Build & Debug".

Is this normal behavior? It seems strange to me to not be able to launch normally on device.

I tried creating a new fresh project and that is also always launched through GDB so it seems that the error is in Xcode and not in a single project.

Are there any Xcode caches, preferences and stuff that might help deleting? I haven't tried uninstall and reinstall yet.
I'm running Xcode 3.2.3 and it's a fresh install on a new computer. I have not tried installing Xcode 4.

Comment: Is it really through gdb, or is it rather that you see the output in Xcode's Console window? (Output in the Console window doesn't mean gdb is attached.)

Comment: It is really through GDB. I can pause and continue whenever I want and if the app crashes I can see the trace in the debugger window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is normal behaviour.  I saw a reference a long time ago that suggested that in fact that was the only way that a process could be remotely launched.

Why is it an issue?